# FEDEX Rating Service - FEDEX_GROUND vs GROUND_HOME_DELIVERY

Tags: php, soap, fedex

When I send a request with FEDEX_GROUND, I get this error. Is there a workaround to switch out the shipping method without explicitly looking for this error and retrying the request?

```
Array
(
[HighestSeverity] => ERROR
[Notifications] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Severity] => ERROR
                [Source] => crs
                [Code] => 924
                [Message] => This shipment qualifies for FedEx Home Delivery.  Please resubmit your request with serviceType Ground Home Delivery.
                [LocalizedMessage] => This shipment qualifies for FedEx Home Delivery.  Please resubmit your request with serviceType Ground Home Delivery.
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Severity] => WARNING
                [Source] => crs
                [Code] => 304
                [Message] => Requested shipment package count did not match the summed total of group package count values; the summed total of group package count values was used to rate.
                [LocalizedMessage] => Requested shipment package count did not match the summed total of group package count values; the summed total of group package count values was used to rate.
            )

    )

[Version] => Array
    (
        [ServiceId] => crs
        [Major] => 10
        [Intermediate] => 0
        [Minor] => 0
    )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you perform the label request, if the service = Ground and res=True then you should switch the service over to Ground Home Delivery. This will resolve the error.

Comment: I wish I could vote this down - It doesn't address the question

Comment: I don't understand why!? The error clearly states - "This shipment qualifies for FedEx Home Delivery.  Please resubmit your request with serviceType Ground Home Delivery." The shipment is set as Ground with Res flagged. You must change the service to Ground Home Delivery to get past the error.

Answer (score 0):

I already had this error when the PackageCount wasn't representing the number of RequestedPackageLineItems.

```
<ns1:PackageCount>2</ns1:PackageCount>

<ns1:RequestedPackageLineItems><...>
<ns1:RequestedPackageLineItems><...>
```

If you have 2 RequestedPackageLineItems, set your PackageCount to two.